# Shell scripting: test if a string contains a character (including chars like '*' and '\')

Tags: string, bash, shell, sh

In a shell script, I have a function `afun` that was passed a few arguments.
I need another function that will help me find out if at least one of those arguments contains a given character which is not known a priori (but it could be any character like `a`, `9`, `*`, `\`, `|`, `/`, `(`, `[` and so on, but not `space`):

```
afun() {
  # Some commands here...
  testchar=... # here I have some logic which decides what character should be tested below
  # Now, call another function to test if any of the args to "afun"
  # contain the character in var "testchar".
  # If it does, print "Found character '$testchar' !"
}
```

The proposed function should be compatible *at least* with **Bash, Dash, Ash** and **ZSH** - because I have a script that needs to run under different Linux distros (Ubuntu, Alpine Linux) installed in Docker containers, and I don't want to declare a dependency on a specific shell interpreter since not all those containers will necessarily have it installed.

Comment: Bash, Dash, Ash and ZSH . That sounds like you're kidding. ;) And the question is not very clear..

Comment: ZSH has more features than Ash, but is it unreasonable what I'm asking? And thanks, I've fixed the variable name (it should be `testchar` instead of `c`)

Comment: Not unreasonable, but should be very difficult IMHO.. :(

Comment: I have edited the question. Let me know if it still lacks clarity.

Comment: I believe somebody cannot come up with a useful solution because shell features vary even with different versions of the same shell.  Now I cant imagine using different shells.. :(

Comment: I have a bash specific solution for you anyways. I would be very happy if you could somehow tweak it to work with different shells..

Comment: @Elifarley, it's not just "more features" -- ash, bash and ksh are compliant with POSIX sh (barring caveats like bash's support for `echo -e`), whereas zsh is intentionally incompatible with the standard (in places where its maintainers decided -- with some basis in fact -- that the standard enforces bad design decisions) unless running in non-default posix mode. That's not to say that writing scripts compatible with both zsh and POSIX-compliant shells can't be done, but it does mean that it requires a bit more care than the usual (ash+bash+ksh) practice of just complying with POSIX.

Comment: BTW, `local` is not defined by POSIX -- if you're going for maximal compatibility, you'll want to do without.

Comment: The question in the title is adequately answered by the duplicate. If you need help looping over a set of strings, perhaps post a new question (but do look for duplicates first; the [Stack Overflow `bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) contains a substantial collection of common questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my proposed shell function:

```
charexists() {
  char="$1"; shift
  case "$*" in *"$char"*) return;; esac; return 1
}
```

And here's how you can use it:

```
afun() {
  # Some commands here...
  testchar=... # here I have some logic which decides what character should be tested below
  # Now, call another function to test if any of the args to "afun"
  # contain the character in var "testchar".
  # If it does, print "Found character '$testchar' !"
  charexists "$testchar" "$@" && echo "Found character '$testchar' !"
}
```

Here's a simple unit test:

```
fun2test=charexists
{ $fun2test '*' 'a*b' && printf 1 ;} ; \
{ $fun2test '*' 'a' '*' '\' 'b#c|+' '\' && printf 2 ;} ;\
{ $fun2test '\' 'a' '*' '\' 'b#c|+' '\' && printf 3 ;} ;\
{ $fun2test '*' 'ab' || printf 4 ;} ; \
{ $fun2test '*' 'a' '' '/' 'b#c|+' '\' || printf 5 ;}; echo
```

It should print `12345` if all 5 tests pass.

I have just tested under Bash, Dash, Ash and ZSH and all went well.

Comment: `charexists "$testchar" $*` -- without the `$*` quoted -- will behave badly if your list of arguments contains, say, `*` -- unless you *want* that to be expanded to a list of filenames in the current directory.

Comment: Indeed! Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Below is my bash specific solution for this :

```
#!/bin/bash
fun()
{
  not_allowed=' ' # Charater which is not allowed
  [[ "$1" =~ $not_allowed ]] && echo "Character which is not allowed found"
}

fun "TestWithoutSpace"
fun "Test with space"
```

Comment: Using the test case found in my solution, your proposed solution only prints `34`, so it fails the first 2 tests.